# Distinct sum in MTD

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I found a distinct values like
This through measure in power bi
unique hc
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
The values which I have shown those are distinct values which I have found by adding measure.
And those are date wise distinct values.
But in MTD I need the sum of the distinct values
Expected MTD-280

But iam getting MTD-70 this is wrong.

Please help me how do I add the distinct values sum In MTD
iam looking at so many sites but iam not getting the answer. Any one please support me for this.

Please help me to get the sum of distinct values in mtd